# MFMailComposer not showing UIAlertController

Tags: alert, mfmailcomposer

Is there any way to show UIAlertController just after presenting MFMailcomposer? UIAlertView was working fine in this scenario. The problem is i think, view controller is changed now. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Hi, got solution. Presenting alertcontroller on presented view rather than self view will solve the problem. 

[self.presentedViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

got solution. Presenting alertcontroller on presented view rather than self view will solve the problem.

[self.presentedViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];